# WooCommerce: How to display item meta data in email confirmation using woocommerce_order_item_meta_end

Tags: php, custom-field, woocommerce-offtopic, hooks

Our store sells software and we're adding a software voucher code to each purchased. Once the purchase is completed (via the `woocommerce_payment_complete` hook) we generate the voucher code and add it to each item purchased via [wc_add_order_item_meta](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_add_order_item_meta.html) method.

Summarized code:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_payment_complete', 'add_voucher_code');

function add_voucher_code( $order_id ) {

    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();

    foreach ($items as $item)   {

        for ($i = 1; $i <= $item['qty']; $i++)  {
            $voucher_code = 'API request based on order information to get voucher code';
            wc_add_order_item_meta($item->get_id(), 'Voucher Code', $voucher_code);
        }
    }     
}
```

For some reason or another the item custom meta shows up on the order confirmation page, but doesn't in the confirmation email. (**problem 1** slaps forehead) So we're utilizing the `woocommerce_order_item_meta_end` hook to add it to the confirmation email. ([wc_get_order_item_meta](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_order_item_meta.html))

Summarized code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'email_confirmation_display_order_items', 10, 4);

function email_confirmation_display_order_items($item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text) {

    echo '<div>Voucher Code: '. wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'Voucher Code') .'</div>';
}
```

**Problem 2** is that added snippet of code shows on the both the order confirmation page (so now it shows twice) and in the order confirmation email. (slaps forehead again)

**Current Problem 2 Solution**
Right now we solved it by adding an if statement which is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52684334/filter-out-unwanted-order-item-meta-data-from-woocommerce-email-notifications/52684694#52684694). Like so:

```
// Only on emails notifications
if( ! (is_admin() || is_wc_endpoint_url() )) {
    echo '<div>Voucher Code: '. wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'Voucher Code') .'</div>';
}
```

This feels like a band-aid fix and any insight/suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this isn't getting much action I'll put our *band-aid* fix as the current solution.

**Problem 1 Solution**
The added item meta data shows on the order confirmation page and does not show on the confirmation email. We solved this by utilizing the `woocommerce_order_item_meta_end` hook to add the extra item meta.

**Problem 2 Solution**
Adding the item meta data via `woocommerce_order_item_meta_end` to the confirmation 
 email also adds it to the confirmation page (visibly duplicating it). We solved this by adding an if statement suggested by @LoicTheAztec [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52684334/filter-out-unwanted-order-item-meta-data-from-woocommerce-email-notifications/52684694#52684694).

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'email_confirmation_display_order_items', 10, 4);

function email_confirmation_display_order_items($item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text) {

    // Only on emails notifications
    if( ! (is_admin() || is_wc_endpoint_url() )) {
        echo '<div>Voucher Code: '. wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'Voucher Code') .'</div>';
    }
}
```

**Resources**
[email confirmation hook visual guide](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-emails/)
[wc_get_order_item_meta docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_order_item_meta.html)
[Filter out unwanted order item meta data from Woocommerce email notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52684334/filter-out-unwanted-order-item-meta-data-from-woocommerce-email-notifications/52684694#52684694)

Answer (score 0):

You could also just only execute the add_action whenever you're in a different action. You could hook into `add_action( 'woocommerce_email_header' );` first and then hook into `woocommerce_order_item_meta_end`. This way we're only doing this whenever the `woocommerce_email_header` action is executed.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', function() {
    add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', [ $this, 'functionThatDoesSomething' ], 10, 2 );
} );
```