# Woocommerce send custom email receipt based on product attribute

Tags: customization, email

I was wondering if someone can point me towards the big picture on how to send a Woocommerce Custom email based on the product attribute. I'm mostly a front end javascript dev, and don't know the Woocommerce ecosystem that well. I've got some Woo products that are event tickets, that I would like the customer to get a different email for. I see under each product you specify an attribute, which would be ticket.

I've got a basic WP plugin going that will house this functionality. I've found some resources on sending custom emails with Woo. So i guess the piece I'm missing would be when a customer buys a product, if it has the ticket attribute, send the custom email. Any input on figuring out how to do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would hook into the woocommerce_thankyou then evaluate the order data.  I see there is a good answer on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42530626/getting-order-data-after-successful-checkout-hook) for hooking and a good answer on [Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/351582/woocommerce-how-to-display-item-meta-data-in-email-confirmation-using-woocommer) for getting the item's meta data into the email.

Comment: Thanks so much!